# Combo box css code

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx

I'm doing a university project with javafx but my css knowledge is very poor and I need some stuff. I have some code that make grey combo-box's border and when you focus it the border change to blue, but when you click it the border change to white and I want that the border keep blue. What I should add to my code?

```
.combo-box-base {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, lightgrey, transparent, white;
    -fx-background-radius: 0, 0, 0, 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.166667em; /* 2 */
}

.combo-box-base:hover  {
    -fx-background-color: transparent,  #6699FF, transparent, white;

}

.combo-box-base:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: .4;
}

.combo-box-base .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, lightgrey, transparent, white;
}

.combo-box-base .arrow {
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.333333em 0.333333em 0.333333em; /* 4 4 4 4 */
    -fx-shape: "M8.124,13.625l4.125-3.375v2.889l-4.125,3.86L4,13.139V10.25L8.124,13.625z";
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0) , 8, 0.0 , 0 , 0 );
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:hover{
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected{
    -fx-background-color: #55c4fe;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #6dcdff;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:pressed, .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected:pressed
{
    -fx-background-color: #d3d3d3;
    -fx-text-fill: #1d1d1d;
}
```

ComboBox on hover

[image]

ComboBox on selection

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this

```
.combo-box-base:hover  {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, #6699FF, transparent, transparent, white;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried both option but didn't work. I can't post images yet so I uploaded two to this server: http://i62.tinypic.com/2exprfl.jpg http://i58.tinypic.com/346tkjo.jpg I want the blue border too when the user click the combobox

Comment: Thanks for edit. The problem with this change is that when I focus an element of the list the border turns white again, it's possible to keep it blue all the time?

Answer (score 0):

you should add "white" instead of the color, simply change this:

```
.combo-box-base .arrow-button {
-fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;}




.combo-box-base {
-fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
-fx-background-radius: 0, 0, 0, 0;
-fx-padding: 0.166667em; /* 2 */}
```